# HTML Image wont load

Tags: html, image, handlebars.js

I'm creating a small website for university. I'm totally new in web dev and got a problem i can't find the answer for. I was searching similar topics for some good time now but i cant the solution.

It´s important to note, that i access this website with localhost:8080/index for example. So the website is not "online". To start the site i have to go inside the folder and cmd -> npm start
We also use Handlebars (if this is somehow important), so pretty much every file is .hbs

My problem is

```
<img src="index.jpg" alt="index">
```

is just not working. It only displays the alt "index" on the page. When i use an global img url (like from wikipedia) its showing me the image. But not when i use "own" images. I was trying diffrent pictures, diffrent names, diffrent locations for the picture but it won't load.

When i use the inspector inside Firefox or Chrome it tells me img don't load(this is translated from germany, i don't know what it tells in english)

impressum.hbs and the picture are inside the same folder
I was copying the picture into every folder but still, it won't load.

Comment: have you set the for the css/js files in app.js like this
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
if you have done some thing like this so you have to move the image into public folder if you don't set the path try this src="/index.jpg" and of-course with the help of inspect element check the url image is coming or not if the issue is still not resolved please contact me via in pm via skype

Answer (score 0):

You may also doublecheck that the pic is .jpg and not .jpeg, which happens sometimes.
So your index.html and your picture are in the same exact folder?

```
<img src="picture.jpg"> picture.jpg is located in the same folder as the current page
    <img src="images/picture.jpg">  picture.jpg is located in the images folder in the current folder
    <img src="/images/picture.jpg"> picture.jpg is located in the images folder at the root of the current web
    <img src="../picture.jpg">  picture.jpg is located in the folder one level up from the current folder
```

Comment: Yes they are in the same exact folder. I have copied paste the picture inside pretty much every folder. it is jpg but i also was trying jpg, jpeg, JPG, JPEG

Comment: try using /index.jpg"  also use instyle tags  width="400" height="400" etc for now just to make sure thats not the issue.

Comment: Still not working. It seems like it is just not uploading the picture into the side. Weird

Comment: what is the file permission of your image under the same directory? run `ls -l index.jpg` and what do you see?

Comment: It is all acces. So i have all the permissions. But one strange thing: Every folder AND the root folder is "writing protected" in their properties. When i change to not writing protected he saves this setting for all. But next time i go inside the property its again writing protected

Answer (score 0):

The solution was an "internal" Problem. The univeristy gives us a framework and somehow you only can access pictures when they are saved inside 1 special folder. So it´s solved. Still i dont understand why they dont tell us this information directly...